# How do you use strict/lose source tracerouting with Cisco IOS

Tags: cisco, routing, cisco-commands, packet-tracer, traceroute

I have been trying to guess the syntax but, I can't figure out how to do it

[image]

Based on the above diagram, what should be the traceroute command on R1 to force the traffic go via `R1->R2->R4`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments, you need source routing enabled on the routers. It is disabled by default for security reasons, and the routing options in a packet will be ignored if source routing is disabled.

Your host must supply the route options in the path. You can use Cisco's extended traceroute to specify the route options, but it will not work unless you have source routing enabled on all the routers in the desired path.

This also forces traffic to be process switched, and this will slow routing. If your desire is to test propagation times, you will find they are slower with source routing.

Once you have finished testing, you should disable it. Your network design is fairly meaningless if the hosts determine the path which traffic will take, and it is a security problem. You are unlikely to find any businesses or Internet carriers/providers which have this enabled.

You can use the extended traceroute. Something like:

```
Router1#traceroute
Protocol [ip]: 
Target IP address: 10.11.12.13
Ingress traceroute [n]: 
Source address: 10.11.1.1
Numeric display [n]:
Timeout in seconds [3]: 
Probe count [3]: 
Minimum Time to Live [1]: 
Maximum Time to Live [30]: 
Port Number [33434]: 
Loose, Strict, Record, Timestamp, Verbose[none]: Loose
Source route: 10.11.2.1 10.11.3.1 10.11.4.1 10.11.5.1 10.11.6.1 10.11.7.1
```

Cisco has documents explaining this command, e.g. [Using the Extended ping and Extended traceroute Commands](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/routing-information-protocol-rip/13730-ext-ping-trace.html#ext_troute). You can search for `cisco extended traceroute` on the Internet.

Comment: Thanks Ron, your comments are valid but they do not address the question. The Cisco CLI allows you to do this; one use case scenario would be to test a path (propagation times) before you switch the traffic through that path.

Comment: You can enable source routing in some Cisco routers, but your host will need to supply the route options, and you can be quite disappointed with the results since it often doesn't work as expected. It is dangerous to leave it enabled.

Comment: I am asking here about using the traceroute command with the strict source routing option. Are you suggesting that I need to enable source route routing before I use this?

Comment: Yes. The route options in a packet will be ignored with source routing disabled on the routers.

Comment: OK I get it I will enable the source routing on the routers but then how do I force the packets to take the path I want using the traceroute command available via Cisco CLI

Comment: You can use the extended traceroute. after you select `loose` or `strict`, you will be prompted for the path, and you can enter a series of hops which you want the packets to take. See my example I added to the answer.